# Filter multiple columns at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Im using angularJS to create a list of items. Now I want to filter so that I can search in multiple columns at the same time. For example if I search for "Bob" all the columns containing "Bob" will show, and then I continue to search for "Bob 073" all columns containing the name "Bob" and the telephone-number that contains "073" will show.

I have created a filter that achieves something similar, but is hardcoded to specific columns and only works if I search for both columns.

```
app.filter('appFilter', function () {
    return function (data, search) {
        if (!search) {
            return data;
        } else {
            var term = search;
            var termsArray = term.split(' ');

            return data.filter(function(item){
                return item.name.indexOf(termsArray[0]) > -1 && item.phone.indexOf(termsArray[1]) > -1;  
           });
        }
    }
});

<input type="search" ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="item in items | appFilter:search )">
    {{item.name}}, {{item.phone}}
</div>
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should use || instead of &&

Comment: please post example on witch list you run `ng-repeat` with `appFilter`.

Comment: @Alexander That does not work, both need to be true else it will search for just one of the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myApp.filter('filterMultiple', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return function (items, keyObj) {
    var filterObj = {
        data: items,
        filteredData: [],
        applyFilter: function (obj, key) {
            var fData = [];
            if (this.filteredData.length == 0)
                this.filteredData = this.data;
            if (obj) {
                var fObj = {};
                if (!angular.isArray(obj)) {
                    fObj[key] = obj;
                    fData = fData.concat($filter('filter')(this.filteredData, fObj));
                } else if (angular.isArray(obj)) {
                    if (obj.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                            if (angular.isDefined(obj[i])) {
                                fObj[key] = obj[i];
                                fData = fData.concat($filter('filter')(this.filteredData, fObj));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (fData.length > 0) {
                    this.filteredData = fData;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    if (keyObj) {
        angular.forEach(keyObj, function (obj, key) {
            filterObj.applyFilter(obj, key);
        });
    }

    return filterObj.filteredData;
}
}]);
```

Usage:

```
arrayOfObjectswithKeys | filterMultiple:{key1:['value1','value2','value3',...etc],key2:'value4',key3:[value5,value6,...etc]}
```

Comment: This helped me create a solution to use searchterms. Thanks!